# why my "import json" is not working in python

Tags: python, json, import

I am importing Json to fetch data, but this command is not working
I already did different things like creating virtual environment, but it's not working

````
```type here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz5L1.png)

HELP ME WITH THIS 
Why is this keep showing me this error
````

Comment: Please edit the question. It appears that the error occurred due to naming the file as "json.py" as json is a standard library in python. Please rename the file and try again. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Your code seems to have some syntax errors. Type here is not valid python. Neither Help me with this, or any other line

Answer (score 1):

Your source file is named `json.py`, which shadows the built-in `json` module. Essentially, your module tries to reimport itself, which is not allowed in Python. To fix it, just name your file something else

Comment: import json


x = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

THIS IS MY CODE 
print(y["age"])

Comment: I CHANGED TH FILE . AND DELETE THAT JSON ONE. NOW IT'S SAYING MY THAT PATH IS NOT CORRECT . CAN U TELL ME WHICH PATH?

Comment: @FarazAhmed072 the file contents seem to be fine, so I guess you forgot to change the command you're running it with. If you previously wrote `python ./json.py`, you should now change it according to how you've renamed the file